# How can I initialize vector<type*> in my class?

Tags: c++, class, stdvector

Why does it have 1000 elements?

```cpp
class node 
{
  public:
    std::vector<node*> symbs;
    int count = 0;

    node() : count(0), symbs(26, nullptr) {}

};
int main()
{
    node *trees;
}
```

[image]

I can use `node *trees = new node;` and it's ok, but I don't want to clean memory. How can I do it differently?

Comment: `std::vector<std::uniquie_ptr<node>> symbs;`?

Comment: @NathanOliver, yes, but any way I want to understand this problem...

Comment: You're accessing garbage memory using a pointer to random data. It's undefined behavior. And putting raw pointers in an array doesn't make you any less responsible for freeing it. If you don't want to clean up your own memory, then none of your types should have the `*` in them. At all.

Comment: @AleksandrDots Understand what problem?  Pointers don't take care of themselves.  You have to do it manually.  The way to avoid that is to use a smart pointer that will clean up after itself.

Comment: You only have _one_ element and that's a `node*`. It doesn't point at any `node` though. It's uninitialized.

Comment: Is node polymorphic? If not just use `std::vector<node>` and rely on move semantics, this is both easier to use and it will keep your memory layout contiguous (which is more cache friendly). Also wrap your nodes in a tree class so you can guarantee the behavior of a tree (e.g. no cyclic dependencies).

Comment: @PepijnKramer `std::vector<node>` will be problematic since the default constructer creates 26 new ones :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Fair enough ;) But that should be fixable by putting the nodes in a tree and only add those children when you need them. One more reason you should never encounter free nodes without a graph/list or tree class to manage them.

Comment: This is not a lot different from any other uninitialized variable.  like `int n;`  You wouldn't expect `n` to hold any particular value unless you initialize it or explicitly assign it a value.  Same goes for your uninitialized `trees` variable.  Maybe `node *trees = nullptr;` is what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

> Why it has 1000 elements?

You have uninitialized pointer which you use to access some random memory and get garbage result aka Undefined Behavior.

> I can use node *trees = new node; and it's ok, but i don't want clean memory. How can I do it in a different way?

You can just create object, not pointer to it:

```
int main()
{
    node trees;
}
```

This object will be created at the point of definition and automatically destroyed at the end of the scope.

As for your vector, if your `node` object owns that sub-nodes it should contain a vector of `std::unique_pointer<node>` or  `std::shared_pointer<node>` depends on ownership. Note - ownership means that 2 nodes should not own each other, otherwise you will get cyclic refernce and memory leak. Using smart pointers you do not have to create and implement destructor and copy/move costructor etc.